# Xamarin Android: Hundreds of warnings saying to check if Nuget packages are compatible

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget, nuget-package

I am building an app, and I have hundred of warnings like this one: "Skipping TPProject.Resource.Drawable.ic_collapse_00000. Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible."

My compile/target framework is Android 8.0, my target Android version is 6.0 and my minimum Android version is 5.1. I have updated all my Nuget packages to the latest versions.

What's wrong??

[image: Warnings]

Comment: have you [tried my fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57378826/1466046)?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not working in that project anymore, but I will test your fix with a copy of the project that I have, to see if it works. Thank you!

Comment: ok, please try it and look if it also helps. took me some time to find this.

Answer (score 8):

This did got rid of the warnings:

- update the Xamarin Extentions
- clean solution
- build solution

Result: all the the warnings are gone but Resource.designer.cs got modified

```
public static void UpdateIdValues()
{
...
lot of new rows
...
}
```

Comment: When you say 'update the Xamarin Extentions', are you referring to making sure the various Xamarin NuGet packages are up-to-date for the offending project?

Comment: Yes, the update of Xamarin Extentions nuget package, this package will automatically update all  essential packages (which probably causing an error)

Answer (score 4):

The errors in your console seem to relate to automatically added resources from the android SDK. Maybe try to get VS to regenerate the resources file by adding a new file (anything, you can remove it after) to the resources directory in the Android project. If that doesn't work try setting the compile and target versions to 8.0 explicitly and do the same thing.

Also, I think that ic_cast_grey is part of the [Support v7 library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/#) so make sure you have that included in your list of Nuget packages.

**Edit**

You should also make sure your Android SDK stuff is up-to-date by running the SDK Manager as admin (assuming you're on Windows and installed it to default Program Files directory).

I've also read that sometimes it helps to remove and re-add the packages so that they refresh their local caches. Maybe you can try that, too.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Richard. When I remove the Resource file, all the warnings go away immediately, however they come back after I rebuild. Also, I have the Support v7 library nuget package installed. The only thing left is to set the the compile and target versions to 8.0 explicitly as you say, however, I'm not really sure where I could do that. Can you point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: @SamyCode Right click the Android project in Solution Explorer and go to Properties. The Application tab on the left has the Compile version and the Android Manifest tab has the Target version.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and fixed it by adding this entry to the csproj:

```
<AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>False</AndroidUseManagedDesignTimeResourceGenerator>
```

to disable the the [managed tool](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/Design-Time-Build-System) and use again the old aapt tool.

Starting with Xamarin.Android 10.0.0.4, shipped with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 Preview 2 or Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.3 Preview 2, Microsoft [downgraded the warning to message/information](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/3243).

So when 16.3 is final, the warnings will go away as they are no real issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sources like [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/272488/#Comment_272488), [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/363736/#Comment_363736) and [that](https://www.telerik.com/forums/nuget-package-versions-compatibility#L6iO5-LvXkqQqQMb8bFDyA) all state the same:

If your project uses different `Xamarin.Android.Support` library version than the included `NuGet` packages (which where built with a specific `Xamarin.Android.Support` library version), than the warnings appear. Don't know if this behavior has been fixed in newer versions, but otherwise you are stuck with this warnings.

You could change the library version for all `Xamarin.Android.Support` libraries, but if you include many `NuGet` packages it is impossible to get all on the same version.

The error appeared for me after upgrading the `Xamarin.Android.Support` libraries and increasing the `TargetFrameworkVersion`. Another solution would be to downgrade this, but I can't because other libraries depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same issue recently. The solution that worked for me was to change the minimum Android version to 6.0:

> If you read the Dependencies section of the Xamarin.Android.Support.*
>   libraries in the NuGet Package Manager, you can see that the
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.* v28.0.0 libraries only support
>   MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0 through MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0.
>
> In short; the v28.0.0 support libraries are meant for Android 6.0-9.0,
>   hence the warnings before we lifted our minimum Android version...

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/128406/xamarin-forms-3-1-resources-warnings-for-android